# I've done a Powerpoint project / I've made a Powerpoint project?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I'm wondering which one is correct? I'll be very grateful if you expain to me.

Comment: You don't *do* a project, and you don't *make* a project, either. You can *finish* a project, or *complete* it, or *participate in* it, or *work on* it, or any number of other things. You can *do* a Powerpoint *presentation*, of course — and that's the elephant in the room right there. What do you even mean by "a Powerpoint project"? What is that? A presentation? A collection of presentations? A Turing machine written in Powerpoint? A Cobol plugin? Entirely unclear. If it was just a presentation, then call it a *presentation*. And that's a thing that you can actually *do*, then.

Comment: PowerPoint is evil. Don’t either make or do it.

Answer (score 1):

One could say one had ***made*** a PowerPoint file, or ***done*** a PowerPoint presentation.

**But a *"project"* is not *"made"* and seldom *"done"*. The first is definitely not idiomatic, and the second not quite right either.

If you are talking of a ***project*** there are other verbs which are more idiomatic e.g. ***perform***, ***take on***, ***complete*** etc.

One could therefore say:

**I have performed/taken on/completed a PowerPoint project**.

Comment: Ozdic separates senses of 'project' before it offers collocates (based on research, of course). However, I'd say OP's example isn't exactly either of the two senses Ozdic considers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, you could have quoted the verbs which *Ozdic* says collocate with *project* - which are ***set up | carry out, run | conceive, plan | launch | fund, support***. There are others, including the three I mentioned in the answer. However notwithstanding having said that projects are not usually "made" - there is a context in which you can "make a project out of something", in the same way that you "make a silk purse from a sow's ear".

Answer (score 0):

[Teaching 101: Classroom Strategies for the Beginning Teacher edited by Jeffrey Glanz](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wIt4Rk7bA5YC&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=%22a+Powerpoint+project%22&source=bl&ots=ZB39q1i90F&sig=ACfU3U1PhBlVj-PnBiw2i10OGKDwbH4SbQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXpMSRs8TnAhXdQkEAHaYnA4Q4ChDoATABegQIChAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20Powerpoint%20project%22&f=false) might be expected to use language appropriately; the publication has a section on using PowerPoint in the classroom. Other than *type*, the DO *PowerPoint project* is used with the verbs *type* (where the more  detailed verb was appropriate) but principally with the more general verb **compile**:

> This unit plan takes students through a five-step process to teach
>   them how to compile a PowerPoint project....

Obviously, 'plan', start', 'improve', complete' ... would be used where appropriate.

Although projects of other natures have (as attested by [Ozdic](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/project)) the collocates (for a new bridge / dam / housing estate / conservation trust etc) *conceive / plan / set up / launch / carry out / run*, and (as set for schoolchildren) *do*, these aren't appropriate here.

After the project has been put together and presented, one would say "I've *given* a PowerPoint presentation [on ....]"

Comment: I would say that that is a classic instance of the sloppy way that the tech industry employs English. How can you "compile a project"? A project is a process not an end product. One can "compile a dictionary", or a "project presentation", but you cannot compile a "project" any more than you can compile a "session cleaning your car". On other matters -  I don't know where you are right now, but the wind ain't half blowing in Berkshire! Wow! Glad I'm not driving in this!

Comment: You may be interested to know that in the OED, all the noun senses of "project" which have it as an end product, rather than an undertaking are declared *Obsolete* - e.g. this one: *a. A plan, draft, scheme, or table of something; a tabulated statement; a design or pattern according to which something is made. Obsolete.*

Comment: A schoolfriend and I handed in a project – _handed in a project_ (on the Napoleonic Wars) – over 54 years ago. Surely you wouldn't contest that usage? I still remember sacrificing some of my precious 'Knowledge' magazines, cutting and pasting, putting together the project. Compiling it, in education-speak. Admittedly, 'handing in a project' may nowadays often refer to a non-physical transfer of data (eg see this 2020 use at [CS.CMU](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/hotc/). But then usages broaden. It's still a finished work.

Comment: You were undoubtedly "given the project", you "worked on the project" and you "handed in the project". (In the same way you were "given homework", "worked on homework" and handed in "homework".) But do you consider that you "made" or "compiled" the project? My guess is that your history teacher would have said something like "What did you discover when you were working on your project?" - never "when you were making , or compiling your project". I think "your project" in that sense is a convenient shorthand for "the results of your project".

Comment: And 'I have performed a PowerPoint project' sounds natural? I'd certainly use 'put together', 'work on' etc. But 'project' = 'piece of work' is fine. You can still hand in a project. So OED is missing something.

Comment: Sense 2b of the noun says *An exercise in which school or college students study a topic, either independently or in collaboration, over an extended period; a piece of research work undertaken by a student or group of students.* But the examples are like this: *2000   J. S. Jones Welsh Boys Too 18   You talked about your class project on the Penrhyn Quarry at Bethesda.* There seems to be no instance where the final end result - the document which presents the findings etc is referred to as "the project". Though I grant that it exists in schoolteacher speech - which I didn't at the outset.

Comment: Perhaps it is a bit like *shopping*. You *go shopping*, or *do the shopping* and you *bring the shopping home*. The OED recognises that one: *2013   C. Tsiolkas Barracuda (2014) 366   Two bags of shopping were on the bench.*
*